# Pro-alternating completion of a free group

Tags: group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $F$ be a free group with $r$ generators. Then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there are exactly $H_n = \left(\frac{n!}{2}\right)^r - 1$ nontrivial distinct homomorphisms from $F$ to $A_n$, the alternating group on $n$ elements. There is a canonical map $$\iota \colon F \to \mathcal{A} = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty A_n^{H_n},$$ where $A_n^{H_n}$ denotes the $H_n$-fold cartesian product of $A_n$. Following some classical results one can verify that this is actually an embedding. Clearly, $\mathcal{A}$ is a profinite group so it makes sense to consider the closure of $\iota(F)$ in $\mathcal{A}$. In a paper by Glebsky (see http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06940) it is briefly mentioned that this completion, let's denote it $\hat{F}_\mathcal{A}$ - the pro-alternating completion of $F$, is actually isomorphic to $\hat{F}$, the profinite completion of $F$. I fail to see why this is the case.

Would anyone mind shedding some light into this either by giving a brief explanation of by giving a reference to some readable material?

Comment: I would like to take a stab at it:   let G^ denote the closure of the image of F into to pro alternating group and let F^ denote the pro completion of F. The embedding F -> G^ extends to F^--> G^ by continuity. The finite quotients of F are isomorphic to the finite quotients if G^ (as a pro system)  so we can map G^ to F^ by universal property.

Comment: I might need a little bit of explanation of the last sentence. What exactly is meant by "The finite quotients of F are isomorphic to the finite quotients if G^ (as a pro system)"? I can see that every finite quotient of G^ is a finite quotient of F^, but not every finite quotient of F^ is a finite quotient of G^. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry about the unclear language. The point in that sentence is the following: to construct F^ we choose a system of decreasing subgroups of F. The universality of F^ implies that there is some freedom in those choices. Now in our situation let us fix (obvious) subgroups B-n of A that generate neighborhoods of identity. Then it is clear that the subgroups Fn of F which are map to F \cap B-n define a neighborhood of identity in F^. So we get a map from G^  to F^.  I hope this is more clear.

Comment: I am afraid it is not. Following the argument it would follow that the pro-p completion is isomorphic to the profinite completion and thus isomorphic to the pro-alternating completion... Again, what am I missing?
Please note, that my knowledge on topological groups is rather thin...

Comment: I am not so sure about that. If we take the integer Z the pro p completions involves Subgroups p^n Z and for a different prime q, the subgroups q^n Z   aren't contained p^n Z. So pro p completion isn't the same as profinite completion.

Comment: I think I get it now. The canonical map from F^ to G^ is obviously onto and since F is residually alternating it is injective on a dense set, hence it must be injective. The problem is that the inverse to this map is not obvious and I have a suspicion that you might need axiom of choice in order to construct it.

Comment: Don't you already need Axiom of Choice to even define the infinite product in the definition or construct the pro-completion of a group?